# How to disable SKU from product page Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, template

How to hide SKU in product page in Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

Open below listed file and just comment out this `<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>` code. I hope it will work for you

> /app/design/frontend/your_theme_package/your_theme/template/catalog/
>   product/view.phtml

and comment out this `<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>` code and check.

Comment: How to remove from cart page?

Comment: I think it need to disable from admin. set sku  attribute value  required no from admin. do not fill value in sku field. it will remove everywhere from whole website.